# Is there a config.yml pattern that will only build PRs to master, and not build master again after the merge?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, config, circleci

My team is getting started with CircleCI. The monthly plan is just about our most hefty subscription fee at the moment. What I'd like to do is only build PRs to master (the default branch), and not build the successive merge commit to master.

We do a good job of keeping our branches up to date with master, so the merge is just a formality. How would I achieve this in the config.yml file?

Someone mentioned a pattern such as:

```
general:
   branches:
      ignore:
         - master
```

But then said that PRs were no longer being built with this method as of 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can achieve this. But you can add an Approval step to your workflow so that the whole jobs won't run if you don't approve. Also you can cancel these jobs anytime. [Approval Workflow](https://circleci.com/blog/manual-job-approval-and-scheduled-workflow-runs/)